# How got out-sample forecast by ARIMA model?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

$y_t = \beta_1x_{1t}+\beta_2x_{2t}+\beta_3x_{3t}+ (1+\phi)\epsilon_{t-1}-\phi\epsilon_{t-2}+\eta_t+\theta\eta_{t-1}$.

How I got the forecast (out-sample prediction)? Suppose, I have $x_{1t}$, $x_{2t}$, $x_{3t}$. I mean how I get $\epsilon_{t-1}$ and $\epsilon_{t-2}$.

Comment: You replace unknown quantities by your best guess for these. So in case of the innovations, that would be zero.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks. How do I get these two variables $\epsilon_{t-1}$ and $\epsilon_{t-2}$. May I generate them from a normal density.

Comment: You do not. You replace them with their expected values.